# CognitoUser: Property 'attributes' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'

Tags: angular

I'm using AWS Amplify, my app is working correctly in local (`ng serve`).
when I try to run `npm run build:serverless:deploy` I get this error:

> ERROR in src/app/nav/nav.component.html(11,15): Property 'attributes' does not exist on type 'Observable'

My nav.component.ts

```
....
loggedUser : Observable<CognitoUser|any> = new EmptyObservable();
subscription : Subscription;

ngOnInit() {
    this._authService.currentUser.subscribe(u => {
        if (u && u.username) {
            this.loggedUser = u;
        } else {
            this.loggedUser = new Observable<CognitoUser|any>();
        }
    }); 
}
```

My package.json

```
....
    "build:serverless": "npm run build:browser:serverless && npm run build:server:serverless",
    "build:prod:deploy": "npm run build:prod && npm run deploy",
    "build:serverless:deploy": "npm run build:serverless && npm run deploy",
    "deploy": "serverless deploy",
....
```

My nav.component.html

```
....
<li *ngIf="(loggedUser && loggedUser?.attributes); then logout else login"></li>
.....
```

Answer (score -2):

You have initially declared `loggedUser` as an observable, so the error you are getting is completely correct, `attributes` does not exist on an Observable.

Your `loggedUser` is not an observable at all, if we look at your further implementation, where you subscribe to an observable and assign the value to `loggedUser`.

So your `loggedUser` should be:

```
loggedUser = <CognitoUser>{};
```

Now, when we have initialized your object, we don't need to safe navigation operator in the template either. You don't **have** to initialize it, you can simply also keep the safe navigation operator and do:

```
loggedUser: CognitoUser;
```

but I like to initialize my variables. It's your choice :)